# Dollar sign and quotes in return component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, listitem

i create a use state in my react component like that:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
```

and in one project in return of component i saw something like this

```
<ListItemButton sx={{ color: `${loading && 'yellow'}` }}>
```

I can't find how that  `` `${x && 'x' }` `` syntax works
Can someone explain to me or show me the documentation of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case `` `${loading && 'yellow'}` `` is the same as `loading && 'yellow'`

Strings surrounded in backticks `` ` `` are called template literals. It allows you tu put variables in strings.

`` `I'm ${name}. I'm ${age} years old.` ``

---

`&&` operators just means 'take the first falsey element and return it. If no falsey element is found, returns the last one.

`0 && "" && "Banana"` will return `0`

`"Banana" && "" && 0` will return `""`

`"Banana" && 1 && 2` will return `2`

Comment: `false && 'yes'` paste this in the browser console and experiment

Comment: I got the explanation wrong for &&, fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

It's logical AND ( **&&** ) operator, and next thing will execute incase if `true` condition

```js
let yellow = true;
console.log( yellow && "Yellow color" )

let blue = false;

console.log( blue && "Blue color" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simple plane [javascript template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
`${loading && 'yellow'}`
```

Will become

```
'yellow'
```

or

```
''
```

Depending on `loading`

Comment: hmm, i think i dont get it. In this example loading it's a boolean

Comment: it's a && operation tho

Comment: I thought that `&&` is so obvious that it doesn't need explanation

Comment: ofc dont need explanation